# How do I get frequency of each value and sum of the frequency if it is less or equal to the value in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
sample = [1,2,2,4,4,3,4,3,4,3]

depot_1=[]
depot_2=[]
tempdepot_1=[]
tempdepot_2 = []

def sample_calc (sample):

    for item_1 in sorted(sample):
        depot_1.append(item_1)
        tempdepot_1.append(sample.count(item_1))


    for item_2 in tempdepot_1:
        depot_2.append(item_2/len(sample))

    tempdepot_3=[ sum( depot_2[:x] ) for x in range( 1, len(depot_2)+1 ) ]


    print(depot_1)
    print(tempdepot_1)
    print(depot_2)
    print(tempdepot_3)

sample_calc (sample)
```

I am trying to get two lists, one is sorted [original list] and second is frequency of each value on the [sorted list] and sum of the frequencies for equal and less value.

Desired output:

```
depot_1     = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
tempdepot_3 = [0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Could you help with [tempdepot_3] list? (without libraries)

Comment: Why.Without.Libraries???

Comment: I would like to learn with build-in python modules, because I am a new python learner and would like to stay away from the library till comprehend the basics.

Comment: OH. So standard library is OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another not so elegant way of doing it without `collections` library is:

```
sample = [1,2,2,4,4,3,4,3,4,3]
depot_1 = sorted(sample)
print(depot_1)

tempdepot_3 = []

freq = depot_1.count(depot_1[0])/len(depot_1)
tempdepot_3.append(freq)

for i in range(1,len(depot_1)):

  freq = depot_1.count(depot_1[i])/len(depot_1)

  if depot_1[i]==depot_1[i-1]:
    tempdepot_3.append(tempdepot_3[i-1])
  else:
    tempdepot_3.append(round(freq + tempdepot_3[i-1],1))

print(tempdepot_3)
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

However it is best for you to use Python's standard libraries to improve your code's performance.

Comment: Thank you! I agree with you to use Python's standard libraries.

Answer (score 0):

So, just get a counter (I'm using `collections`, simple enough to do yourself with a plain `dict` though). Then I get a mapping of cumulative proportions, them use the mapping to build the final list:

```
>>> import collections
>>> sample = [1,2,2,4,4,3,4,3,4,3]
>>> N = len(sample)
>>> depot = sorted(sample)
>>> counts = collections.Counter(depot)
>>> counts
Counter({4: 4, 3: 3, 2: 2, 1: 1})
>>> p = 0
>>> props = {}
>>> for k, v in sorted(counts.items()): # Necessary to sort, dicts are unordered
...     p += v
...     props[k] = p / N
...
>>> props
{1: 0.1, 2: 0.3, 3: 0.6, 4: 1.0}
```

Finally:

```
>>> tempdepot = [props[x] for x in depot]
>>> tempdepot
[0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: Great, Thank you. I will try to do it without [collections] library.

Comment: @Denis implementing a `Counter` is *very* easy with a `dict`. A `Counter` inherits from `dict` and works just like a `dict`, but it is specialized for *counting*.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification, I will look into documentation of the {counter} to better understand how it works behind the curtain.